# Null value in List instead of a name

Tags: c#, list, sqlite, unity-game-engine

I'm using a database to store collections of location points and I'm trying to create a list that gets rid of duplicates. It partially working so far. Currently when I check the count of my list via

```
Debug.Log("There are " + GameManager.driftTables.Count() + " drift sets in the list.");
```

I get a correct count back. but when I try to return the name of each row via

```
foreach (AllDrifts drift in GameManager.driftTables)
            {
                Debug.Log(drift.name);
            }
```

I get Null for every single one. What am I doing incorrectly here?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Linq;
using SimpleSQL;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;

public class SQLiteActions : MonoBehaviour
{
    int driftCount;

    public void GetDriftTablesList()
    {
        GameManager.driftTables =
            DriftsDatabaseManager.Query<AllDrifts>(
                "SELECT DISTINCT driftID " +
                "FROM Drift"
            );

        foreach (AllDrifts drift in GameManager.driftTables)
        {
            Debug.Log(drift.name);
        }

        Debug.Log("There are " + GameManager.driftTables.Count() + " drift sets in the list.");
    }
}

public class AllDrifts
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What do you think `SELECT DISTINCT driftID` does? Do you think it returns the `name`? Or just the `driftID`?

Comment: I thought it would return the name

Comment: Okay, right, so that was my question. I'm storing, and getting null for the name of each distinct drift stored in GameManager.driftTables, and what I'm wanting to do is set the name of each list item in GameManager.driftTables to the same distinct name that gets found from the query "SELECT DISTINCT driftID FROM Drift"

Comment: You need to change `driftID` to the name of your name column.

Comment: "to the same distinct name that gets found from the query `SELECT DISTINCT driftID FROM Drift`". That's a bit the same as choosing the `dog` from `{ red, green, blue }`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by no longer using DISTINCT and instead just finding the first time a DriftIndex value shows up in the list and discarding all duplicates after that like so.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Linq;
using SimpleSQL;

    public class DriftSets
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int DriftIndex { get; set; }
        public string DriftID { get; set; }
        public string DriftDateTime { get; set; }
        public string DriftName { get; set; }
        public string DriftStep { get; set; }
        public float DriftLat { get; set; }
        public float DriftLong { get; set; }
        public string DriftTexLocation { get; set; }
    }

    public class SQLiteActions : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public static SQLiteActions instance = null;
        // reference to the database manager in the scene
        public SimpleSQLManager DriftsDatabaseManager;

        private string sql;

        public void GetDriftTablesList()
        {
            sql =
                "SELECT MIN(DriftIndex), DriftID, DriftName, DriftDateTime, DriftTexLocation  " +
                "FROM Drift " +
                "GROUP BY DriftID " +
                "ORDER BY DriftDateTime DESC";

            GameManager.driftSets = DriftsDatabaseManager.Query<DriftSets>(sql);

            foreach (var driftSet in GameManager.driftSets)
            {
                Debug.Log(driftSet.DriftName);
            }
        }
     }
```